# İnterfaces exceeds the height of the screen

Tags: 12.04, 13.10, screen

I use a notebook with small screen, `1024:600` resolution with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. When I try to save or open a document, the interface is exceeding the height of the screen leaving the buttons out of screen from the bottom.

I know I can resize the interface but it is really bothering me to do that every single time. Is there a way to change the settings for the default location and size of such interfaces universally ?

This is the only real reason why I can't recommend Ubuntu to other people who are using similar devices. It is uncomfortable.

I also have a question about the versions. There is a 12.04 and 13.10 release. It says on the page 12.04 has long term support, 13.10 has support for nine months. I have to say that it is confusing to write it like this. My idea was that 13.10 is only good for nine more months. Then it is garbage, history. So I installed 12.04.

Should I install 13.10 ?

What happens after nine months ?

Comment: For the first problem, reducing the font size and other things in use the Tweak Tool can help A LOT. For the versions of Ubuntu, see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). 13.10 would not be garbage straight away - it just would not be supported. After the end date, installing new packages and updating can be difficult - but there are options to upgrade to the newest Ubuntu version anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful response. I look at the tweak tool, it does help but I'm okay using it this way reaching the buttons using the "tab" key. But there has to be a way to fix this in future releases. Of course I know it is easier said than done. But either there has to be a universal size limit to limit the extends of all windows to the screen resolution and adds a scroll bar if the contents exceed the window or if that is not possible there can be a universal zoom function that automatically zooms out the content if it exceeds the resolution to fit it inside the screen.

Comment: When I get around to it I might find the commands I used.. but I used to use a laptop with a screen of 1024x600, and I spent a fair while sorting that out. That's now gone, and I have two other ones with 1024x768 and 1366x768 screens, and even on these things on the screen still seem to big... The problem is, with more and more HD TVs and monitors, the designers tend to forget that some are still using small screens... What I did, when I could, was attach an external monitor (the 1024x768 one), so I could use that as the screen, or just if the content of my laptops screen overflowed.

Comment: It is a netbook actually. I have to use it to carry around and it has like a ten inch screen so external monitor is not an option; but anyway it is just a glitch. I can live with it. Thanks again. Have a nice time.